# Return SQL result from webservice to android

Tags: c#, android, xml, web-services

How would I return an sql result from a c# webservice? the result from the statement will be a product and contain properties like property id and property name etc. it will return about 6 values in total. how would I convert the sql response into an xml format and return it so that I can parse in an android application??

Answer (score 1):

You should use `JSON`, which can easily be parsed in Android (look at this [tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/)). In C# you can use the `Json.Write(data, Response.Output);` function